# Left crankshaft arm broken - can I use a different manufacturer?

Tags: crankset

Good evening,

My left crankshaft broke on my Voodoo Masala hybrid bike (Halfords). It has a Suntour XCT9 crankshaft.

Frustrating it’s cheaper to buy and entire replacement Crankshaft than the left arm alone. My question is can I use any 175 left arm or am I left working out what replacement crankshaft to put on it?

Thanks,

Paul

Comment: Don't forget that left pedals have a left-hand thread, when you're taking it off and most importantly when you're putting it back on

Answer (score 2):

Generally yes, its not a problem, if the cosmetics are not a problem :)

You may find the Q Factor (how far apart the pedals are) changed and a pedals a little offset from center, but in reality this is unlikely to cause a big issue for most riders.

Comment: Thank you! You’ve just saved my Sunday (was about to be spent changing the whole thing)